# INSERT INTO Fields default value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load data from one table to another with this query:

```
INSERT INTO survols (Depart) SELECT Depart FROM survols_temp;
```

"Depart" is one column among others.

I get this error message:

MySQL a répondu : Documentation

> #1364 - Field 'date_UTS' doesn't have a default value

The field "date_UTS" is another column in both tables.
Are there any constraints refering to default value in this particular context? Should I provide a default value for each column?

Note: I have the same message if I select all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your table survols is missing a default value on date_UTS

When you insert a new row, you need to specify all values that haven't git a DEFAULT  Value

So for your date_UTS the column creation should be

```
date_UTS TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Or

you can add the current timestamp into the select and insert

```
INSERT INTO survols (Depart,date_UTS ) SELECT Depart,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM survols_temp;
```